# Aleatoriedad en arreglos? JS

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un reproductor de musica, y quiero aplicar la aleatoriedad, dicho reproductor tiene un arreglo en donde estan todas las musicas, si activo la aleatoriedad me deberia salir un numero desde 0 hasta la posicion del arreglo, lo puedo hacer asi, pero con el math random se puede repetir el mismo numero dos veces seguidas, para eso tengo que hacer una probabilidad pero no lo tengo muy claro como seria, es decir, 100 canciones, cada cancion tiene la misma posibilidad de salir, es decir que los numeros que estan entre el 0 y el 100 todos, pueden salir por igual, pero no lo tengo muy en claro, si pudieran darme una idea, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efectivamente, las funciones pseudoaleatorias de tipo `rand()` proporcionan distribuciones uniformes, todos los números tienen la misma probabilidad de salir. Lo que no implica que no puedan salir canciones repetidas. Un dado también sigue una distribución uniforme y las caras pueden salir más de una vez.

Lo que deberías hacer, si quieres evitar repeticiones, es sacar de tu array las canciones que ya hayas reproducido. Tal y como harías con una baraja: tú decides si devuelves la carta al montón o te quedas con ella.

En estos casos lo que se suele hacer, no es elegir una canción de forma aleatoria, sino ordenar la lista aleatoriamente, así te aseguras de que no haya repetidos.

Espero haberte aclarado, déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: he pensando tambien en eso de ordenar todo el array aleatoriamente y ya despues reproducirlo y no preocuparme, ahorita mismo estoy guardando en una variable el ultimo numero random, entonces si es repetido volver a llamar la funcion hasta que no sea repetido y volverlo a guardar, pero creo que por cuestiones de "rendimiento" es mejor ordenarlo aleatoriamente desde el principio y ya despues reproducirlo